# How can I enable hoisting when using static variables and fields?

Tags: javascript, class, static, hoisting

I am learning about `static` methods and fields to use in my app. 
 I have written the following codes to test what I have learned:

```js
class ClassWithStatic {
  static childclass = new SubClass("Hello");
  
  static writeIn() {
    console.log("Hello world!");
  }
}

class SubClass {
  constructor(text) {
    console.log(text);
  }
}

ClassWithStatic.writeIn();
```

However, this code returned an error; `Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'SubClass' before initialization`. When I searched this keyword in a browser, I found out that the error had occurred because **Hoisting is not working**.
How can I solve this problem **without changing the order of the classes**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, actually, classes **are** hoisted, but its values are not automatically initialized (**class must be defined before it can be constructed**).

That's basically the main difference between classes and functions,
as functions will be hoisted and initialized (so you call them before they are defined code-wise), but classes must be defined prior to constructing them. So I'm afraid you'll have to push the Class declaration above.

Check for more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).